# Find percentage of NA values per month and year in a list of dara frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

I have a list of 83 csv files with three variables.

I have created new date columns including, month and year.

One of my dataframes from the list looks like this:

```
> head(estaciones$AeropuertodeBocas_93002)
        Date Tx2m Tn2m   Pr year month day
1 1988-01-01 27.4 23.1 41.3 1988     1   1
2 1988-01-02 29.8 24.0  0.3 1988     1   2
3 1988-01-03 30.4 24.0  0.4 1988     1   3
4 1988-01-04 30.0 24.2  2.4 1988     1   4
5 1988-01-05 29.6 23.2  9.1 1988     1   5
6 1988-01-06 30.0 23.1  5.2 1988     1   6
```

I would like to create a new file with the percentage of NA values per variable and per month and year. For example Jun 1988: 2% of missing values for variable "Pr" and dataframe "x".

I have tried using:

```
na_by_month <- map(estaciones, ~ .x %>%
                 mutate(Month=month(Date), Mis = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
                 group_by(Month) %>% 
                 summarise(Sum=sum(Mis), Percentage=mean(Mis)))
```

This is only calculating missing values percentage for each month for the whole series and not per year.

Data (one of several dfs):

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(6574, 
6575, 6576, 6577, 6578, 6579), class = "Date"),
Tx2m = c(27.4, 29.8, 30.4, 30, 29.6, 30), 
Tn2m = c(23.1, 24, 24, 24.2, 23.2, 23.1), 
Pr = c(41.3, 0.3, 0.4, 2.4, 9.1, 5.2), 
year = c(1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988 ), 
month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = 1:6), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I create a new file containing percentage of missing values for each of my data frames inside the list, per month and per year? Thank You

Comment: Please provide data: `dput(head(estaciones$AeropuertodeBocas_93002))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to calculate the percentage of missing values by month/year *and* just by year you could write a function that you can then map to your list of dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)
library(rlang)

ldf <- list(df, df, df)

f <- function(data, ...){
  v <- enquos(...)
  data %>%
    group_by(!!! v) %>%
    summarize(across(Tx2m:Pr,
                     list(missing = ~ mean(is.na(.))),
                     .names = paste0("{.col}_{.fn}_", quo_name(v[[1]]))),
              .groups = "drop")
}

miss <- imap(ldf, ~ left_join(f(.x, month, year), f(.x, year), by = "year"))

write.xlsx(miss, "output.xlsx")
```

**How it works**

1. You provide the function `f` your dataframe and the variables you want to group by and it will calculate the percentage of missing values for those group by variables. For example, `f(df, month, year)` will group your data by `month` and `year` and calculate the percentage of missing values for each variable in the range `Tx2m:Pr`.

```
f(df, month, year)
  month  year Tx2m_missing_month Tn2m_missing_month Pr_missing_month
  <int> <int>              <dbl>              <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1  1988                  0                  0                0
```

```
f(df, year)
   year Tx2m_missing_year Tn2m_missing_year Pr_missing_year
  <int>             <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>
1  1988                 0                 0               0
```

Note: the order of your grouping variables matters here. The first group by variable is used to construct the output variable names (eg `Tn2m_missing_month`).

2. If you want the number of missing by month/year and by year for each element of your list, then we can apply this function using `imap` and merge the results by `year`.

```
left_join(f(df, month, year), f(df, year), by = "year")
 month  year Tx2m_missing_month Tn2m_missing_month Pr_missing_month
  <int> <int>              <dbl>              <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1  1988                  0                  0                0
# ... with 3 more variables: Tx2m_missing_year <dbl>,
#   Tn2m_missing_year <dbl>, Pr_missing_year <dbl>
```

Note: The missing by year will be repeated for each month within the year.

3. Lastly, `write.xlsx` will write a list of dataframes to an Excel workbook, where each sheet will be an element of your list.

---

If I've misunderstood your post and you only want the percentage missing by month within year then you can simplify this to:

```
miss <- imap(ldf, ~ f(.x, month, year))
```

**Plot**

To plot you could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)

plots <- imap(miss, ~ .x %>% 
       select(ends_with("year")) %>% 
       distinct() %>% 
       pivot_longer(cols = -year,
                    names_pattern = "(.*?)_(.*)",
                    names_to = c("var", NA)) %>%
       mutate(date = ymd(year, truncated = 2L)) %>% 
       ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = var, group = var)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_line() +
       scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
       scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", 
                    date_labels = "%Y")
)

plots[[1]]
```

where each variable is a line, it's y-axis value is the percent missing, and the x-axis is the year.

[image]

Note: with the given data in the example, the graphic is not that interesting and gives a warning about there being only one point. Additionally, all the points are overlapping on the same (x,y) coordinate with the given data.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked for calculating what I needed. Do you know any way I can visualize this? Especially the percentage of missing values per year per data frame?

Comment: @Adi You're welcome. I've updated my answer to include plotting code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(6574, 6575, 6576, 6577, 6578, 6579), class = "Date"),
                     Tx2m = c(27.4, 29.8, 30.4, 30, 29.6, 30), Tn2m = c(23.1, 24, 24, 24.2, 23.2, 23.1),
                     Pr = c(41.3, 0.3, 0.4, 2.4, 9.1, 5.2),
                     year = c(1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988 ),
                     month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = 1:6),
                row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

nongroup_vars <- setdiff(colnames(df),c('year','month'))
nongroup_vars_mr <- paste0(nongroup_vars,'_missing_ratio')

df %>%
group_by(month,year) %>%
summarise_all(function(x) mean(is.na(x))) %>%
ungroup %>%
rename_with(~nongroup_vars_mr,all_of(nongroup_vars))
```

it says missing ratios for each group.

**output;**

```
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  month  year Date_missing_ratio Tx2m_missing_ratio Tn2m_missing_ratio Pr_missing_ratio day_missing_ratio
  <dbl> <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>
1     1  1988                  0                  0                  0                0                 0
```